# The reference of the object changes in every debug

Tags: java, object, reference, pass-by-reference

Doubtlessly, this question is asked already (may be many times) but I could not find the correct keywords to find them.

Basically, my question is about the object references. What I know is that the object references points the objects physical location on the memory. However, when I debug my code and every time when I debug, I get a difference object reference for the same object.

For example, when I firstly debugged my code and the reference of a button looks like

> INFO  [sysout] [AWT-EventQueue-0]
>   [Ljava.awt.event.ComponentListener;@28be012c

at the second time, it is

> INFO  [sysout] [AWT-EventQueue-0]
>   [Ljava.awt.event.ComponentListener;@31a056d8

My related questions are;

1.Is the part after (@) symbol (a.k.a @28be012c) reference to the object, if yes, it is something like ip address, which changes continiously?

2.Is there a way to obtain an address, which does not change over time (like a Mac-address)

Any answer or link related to these questions will be highly appreciated.

### Edit

I am debugging in this scenario. There is a button and everytime when this button is clicked, the debugger stops at this point. That is to say, the program is not started from the beginning.

Comment: Define `"each time I debug"` please. Do you mean that you're running the program anew each time? And if so, then you should not be surprised that the object's hashCode changes with each run.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I editted my answer.

Comment: if you are in `IDE` then you can jump back too ;)

Comment: @HelloWorld I find the **jump back** not consistent in debugger.

Comment: You ususally see output like "SomeClassName@28be012c" when the "toString()" method has not been overridden.  You might be able to get something useful by overriding "toString()".  I am not sure because I don't know precisely what you are looking for (i.e. do you want to know where in memory an object is located or do you merely want to be able to uniquely and repeatedly be able to identify an object)

Comment: @Ivan In the GUI, I am currently working on, there are 4 buttons. Previously, this GUI is really bad implemented and it is not open to the new features. However, now I need to manipulate two buttons of these 4 buttons (these buttons do not have any references, they are simply added to the frame and the references were not stored). Now, I am trying to get these two specific buttons in a consistent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the part after (@) symbol (a.k.a @28be012c) reference to the object, if yes, it is something like ip address, which changes
>   continiously?

The part after the `@` is `Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`. The `hashCode`method is not designed to return the same value every time it is invoked for different runs (even if the object being created has the same value). It is also not mandatory that the returned value is related to the memory. JVM spec specifies that a unique value should be returned, but it doesn't specify "how".

> Is there a way to obtain an address, which does not change over time
>   (like a Mac-adress)

No. Each run of the JVM will almost always give different hashcodes (unless you override the `hashCode` method to return something else.